# How would I add the results of a 'for' loop into a dictionary?

Tags: python

I am required to take 52 random outputs of cards. I got that in a *for* loop. The problem is, I need to save that output inside a variable.`

```
import random
r=random.randint(0, 9)

cards={'Spades':r, 'Clubs':r, 'Hearts':r, 'Diamonds':r,'Jack':10, 'King':10, 'queen':10,"Aces":1}
print(cards)

cards2={}

for i in range(52):
    global res
    res = key, val = random.choice(list(cards.items()))
    print("Your deck contains " + str(res))
    cards2.update(i) # All output should go in here
```

I tried using cards2.update, but it didn't work.
I also tried using cards2.(keys).
I just need to create 52 random samples and store them as dictionary value pairs.

Comment: Don't do double assignations (`foo = bar = baz`). And avoid using `global`, *in general* is a bad practice (here, in particular, is also unnecessary).

Comment: `but it didn't work` Saying "it didn't work" is not a helpful description of the problem.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly `r=random.randint(0, 9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the double assignment (res = key, val). And I don't see any point in using a global variable here. Just do _dict[key] = value as shown below, and it will work fine. Also remember that you can’t get all 52 random cards, because if the key exists then the value will be replaced.

```
import random
r = random.randint(0, 9)

cards = {'Spades':r, 'Clubs':r, 'Hearts':r, 'Diamonds':r,'Jack':10, 'King':10, 'queen':10,"Aces":1}
print(cards)

cards2 = {}

for i in range(52):
    key, val = random.choice(list(cards.items()))
    cards2[key] = val

print(cards2)
```